How can i run chromium browser from terminal in Openfyde OR Chormium OS
I am using OpenFyde / Chromium OS and I need to run the Chromium browser from the terminal. Specifically, I want to open Chromium with certain parameters like setting the zoom factor and starting in full screen mode.
Could someone please provide detailed instructions on how to achieve this?
Here is what I am looking to do:
Launch Chromium from the terminal.
Set the zoom factor to a specific value (e.g., 1.25).
Start Chromium in full screen mode.
Any help with the exact command(s) and any necessary additional steps would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
